# IP Address is changing

Tags: dns, ip, subdomain, windows-server

Okay. So normally I work on an iMac, but I had to switch over to a PC for a project that I'm working on. I was told to download Web Server Suite. I did so and found what was called a Private IP Address. I pointed a subdomain to that and it worked! The index.php page that I put in `C:\www\webroot\` worked! But when I went to go try this today, the IP changed. It went from `http://192.168.0.149`/ to today `http://192.168.0.139/`.. I don't get why it's doing this.

I also want to note. I normally don't host my websites on a home computer. The only reason this one is like this is because I need it to be able to post results files every second to the webroot folder.

Anyone know why this is doing this? Or (better yet) does anyone have any tips on using this program?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should set up a static IP address. You should probably pick one in the 192.168.0.1-254 range, since that's the range the other addresses were in. It looks like your getting addresses in the middle of the range (139, 149), so you should pick one near the lower or higher end to make sure you don't get duplicates. Here's a guide on how to set up a static IP for Windows:

http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/19249/how-to-assign-a-static-ip-address-in-xp-vista-or-windows-7/

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I thought this is what I needed to do. But I wasn't for sure and I didn't know how to. Thanks again!